# ActionLink in Table MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

*Edit: I have read and implemented the method oulined in [this article](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/ajaxactionlink-and-htmlactionlink-in-mvc.html) but this does not work.*

I have the following table which is populated correctly.

```
<table class="table">
   <tr>
       <th>Product</th>
       <th>File Name</th>
       <th>Release Date</th>
       <th>Size</th>
       <th></th>
   </tr>
   @{
       if (Model != null)
       {
           foreach (var item in Model.Uploads)
           {
               <tr>
                   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)</td>
                   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DisplayName)</td>
                   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)</td>
                   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Size)</td>
                   <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete File", "Upload", "Tools", new { id = item.DisplayName }, null)</td>
               </tr>
           }
       }
   }
</table>
```

I also have a controller with the action

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteUser(
    AdministratorViewModel model, string userName)
{
    // Do amazing stuff...
    return Index();
}
```

I want to pass to this action the username that was selected for deletion. I thought I could achive this with `@Html.ActionLink` as above, but this is not the way to go.

**How can I pass the selected username that was selected to my action method?**

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit:* changing the Ajax code to the following (using `Index` as the called method)

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Remove",
    "Index", 
    "Tools",
    new
    {
        model = item,
        userName = item.UserName
    },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    })
```

and changed the name of the `DeleteUser(AdministratorViewModel model, string userName)` method to `Index(AdministratorViewModel model, string userName)`. This now fires the `Index` method in the `ToolsController`. But the method called is the NON-POST attributed method(!?) so I now have two questions:

1. How can it be calling the method not marked with `[HttpPost]` attribute?
2. Why can I call the `DeleteUser` method using Ben Griffiths' answer below?
3. How can I call my `DeleteUser` method in the Tools controller and pass in the model and the name of the user I want to delete?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fourth argument to the overload of the ActionLink extension method that you are using when you call

```
Html.ActionLink("Delete File", "Upload", "Tools", new { id = item.DisplayName }, null)
```

is for the `route values` parameter, which you can use to pass data back to your controller.

Currently, in the above call, the `Upload` action method on the `Tools` controller will be receiving an `id` argument. If you want to pass a display name back to your DeleteUser action method, you could use

```
Html.ActionLink("Delete User", "DeleteUser", "[ControllerName]", new { userName = item.DisplayName }, null)
```

However, the `DeleteUser` method is decorated with the `HttpPost` attribute, meaning that the action will only accept requests that use the post method. This means that you have three options:

(1) Remove the [HttpPost] attribute from the action method - probably NOT a good idea, since I imagine you don't want to be exposing this action to get requests for good reason.

(2) Use a form containing a submit input and a hidden DisplayName input instead of a link.

(3) Use the AjaxHelper.ActionLink extension method to make an asynchronous postback to your controller. e.g.:

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Delete User", "DeleteUser", "[ControllerName]", new { userName = item.DisplayName }, new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod = "Post" })
```

### Update: a more complete example of the third option

Here's a working (albeit very simple) example of the third option. I'm not 100% sure what the ultimate goal is, so rather than try to provide a realistic example I've tried to create one that is simple but clear. Note that I've omitted the handling of the anti forgery token to aid in this clarity, but I've stuck with an `async` action method so as not to deviate too far from real life.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    private async Task<string> Delete(string displayName) {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return string.Format("{0} has been deleted", displayName);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<JsonResult> DeleteItem(string displayName, int product) {

        Task<string> deleteTask = Delete(displayName);

        return new JsonResult() {
            Data = new { 
                product = product,
                result = await deleteTask }
        };
    }



    public ActionResult Index() {

        AdministratorViewModel model = new AdministratorViewModel() {
            Uploads = new List<ItemModel>() {
                new ItemModel() {
                    DisplayName = "First one",
                    Product = 1,
                    ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now,
                    Size = 11
                },
                new ItemModel() {
                    DisplayName = "Second one",
                    Product = 2,
                    ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    Size = 12
                }
            }
        };


        return View(model);
    }

}
```

Model:

```
public class AdministratorViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<ItemModel> Uploads { get; set; }
}
```

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
        @RenderSection("scripts", false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Home/Index view:

```
 @model AdministratorViewModel

 <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>Release Date</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @{
        if (Model != null) {
            foreach (var item in Model.Uploads) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DisplayName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Size)</td>
                    <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Remove", "DeleteItem", "Home", new { displayName = item.DisplayName, product = item.Product }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "itemDeleted" }, new { id = item.Product })</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
</table>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        var itemDeleted = function (data) {
            var $link = $('#' + data.responseJSON.product);
            $link.parents('tr')
                 .children()
                 .css('text-decoration', 'line-through');

            $link.remove();

            alert(data.responseJSON.result);
        };
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This `@Ajax.ActionLink` is sending me to the URL `http://localhost:52531/Tools/DeleteUser?userName=Alan` which is not what I want. How can i make this work?

Comment: What is the URL that you want to post to?

Comment: I just want to call my Action method inside the `ToolsController`. The action method I want to call is `DeleteUser` and the controller is called `ToolsController`, so i have tried the following `@Ajax.ActionLink("Remove", "DeleteUser", "Tools", new { userName = item.UserName }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" })` how can i amend this to call the action?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean - the browser is redirecting to that URL? You need to have the MVC Unobtrusive Ajax JavaScript library loaded on your page in order for it to work properly - you need a script along the lines of `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>`

Comment: Hi Ben, this has not helped me. Not sure why these sorts of operations are so difficult. I have a book but it is like reading a riddle...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Here's a reasonably clear little tutorial that talks through the steps required - hopefully it might help: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/

Comment: Hi Ben, I have now read pretty much all I can get my hands on. I appear to be doing this correctly but I still can't get this to work. I have edited my question, would you be able to take a look and advise? Thanks again for your time it is most appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I can answer your 3 questions without seeing more of your code, but I've updated my answer with an example of what I had in mind when I suggested using AjaxHelper.ActionLink

Comment: Thanks very much indeed for this. It is greatly appreciated. I can run this, but when I put this in to my site, it doesn't work. Grrrrr. I am clearly doing something foolish. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think first you have to handle the url by adding routing like

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{User}/{DeleteUser}/{username}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Coupled with the answer above I belive i am almost there. I am now getting "Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Tools/DeleteUser" and the requested URL is "http://localhost:52531/Tools/DeleteUser?userName=Alan" but the MapRoute above is the default one...

Comment: It is unlikely that there is any need for you to add a custom route in order to achieve this, unless you already had a complicated routing setup? - otherwise, I would leave your routing table alone. Is the DeleteUser method an action on your Tools controller, and is the Tools controller at the root of your site (i.e. not within an Area)?